# Insert new row into a section of UITableView based on selected row in UIPickerView - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uipickerview

I have a custom inline UIPickerView (essentially just a expanding/collapsing UIPickerView) and there are 3 options (rows) in the picker view: "Weekly", "Monthly" and "Enter Manually". What I am trying to accomplish is that if a user chooses the row "Enter Manually", a new row is inserted below the row containing the custom UIPickerView (which would contain a custom TextInputCell I have created - but thats aside from the matter). The UITableView represents a form where the user can create an "event" so to speak. There are 4 sections and each section has a different amount of rows, some rows have expanding/collapsing UIPickerViews and others have custom UITextFields, and others have expanding/collapsing UIDatePickers. I only want this to happen for 1 particular UIPickerView, but I cannot seem to get it working. I had tried something like this in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` for when the UIPickerView is collapsed from selecting it's row:

```
   tableView.beginUpdates()
    if(cell.isKindOfClass(PickerCell)) {
        let pickerTableViewCell = cell as! PickerCell
        if(!pickerTableViewCell.isExpanded() && pickerTableViewCell.rightLabelText() == numClasses[2]) {
            alertOptions.insert("Number of Weeks", atIndex: 1)
            numberOfRowsAtSection[2] = 5
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([
                NSIndexPath(forRow: alertOptions.count-3, inSection: 2)
                ], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        }
    }
    tableView.endUpdates()
```

The `numClasses` is an array with the UIPickerView row data:

```
let numClasses = ["Weekly", "Monthly", "Enter Manually"]
```

All the UITableView data is in separate arrays for each section like follows:

```
var numberOfRowsAtSection: [Int] = [3, 4, 4, 3]

let mainOptions = ["Client Name", "Invoicing Email", "Invoicing Address"]
let dateOptions = ["All Day", "Starts", "Ends", "Time Zone"]
var alertOptions = ["How Many Classes", "Shown on Calendar As", "Alert by Email", "Alert by Text"]
let billingOptions = ["Amount Charged", "Tax Included", "Billing Date"]
```

And then I suppose I would just put a condition for everything between `tableBeginUpdates()` and `tableEndUpdates()` to test if it was the right UIPickerView like:

```
if(pickerViewTableCell.pickerView == numClassesPicker.pickerView) { ... }
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible or am I on the right track? Help!

Here are some images for a better visual:

Prior to selecting "Enter Manually":

[image: Before]

During selecting "Enter Manually", UIPickerView is expanded:

[image: during]

And after, with it now collapsed and "Enter Manually" Selected, 
What I'm going for here is to now have a new row between "How Many Classes" and "Show on Calendar As":

[image: After]

Comment: Can you post a picture of your UI that you explain in your first paragraph? It's a little hard to visualize what you're saying and a pic would help a lot.

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs The whole table is created programatically so unfortunately if I take a picture of the view in story board it's just an empty table

Comment: Just run it in simulator and take a screenshot. It's been on a hour and no one else has responded. It'll help you get an answer

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs Okay I've uploaded 3 images!

Comment: So the area of the tableView that part is in is it's own section correct?

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs ["How Many Classes", "Shown on Calendar As", "Alert by Email", "Alert by Text"] are in Section 2 together. Everything between the light grey separator are together in sections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `alertOptions`, just add a new object and reload the tableView after you are finished with the action in the pickerView.

Comment: can you give me an example pls

Comment: `numberOfRowsAtSection[2] = 5` shouldn't it be `numberOfRowsAtSection[1] = 5`. What's not happening the way it should?

Comment: No numberOfRowsAtSection: [Int] = [3, 4, 4, 3] = [0,1,2,3], numberOfRowsAtSection[2] refers to alertOptions

Comment: Because I hadn't used tableView.reloadData() this was the main issue so I will mark this as correct, but I've also answered the question with my implementation that works exactly how I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main issues was that I was not using `tableView.reloadData()` but aside from that, the implementation that I ended up coding was:

```
        tableView.beginUpdates()

        if(cell.isKindOfClass(PickerCell)) {

            let pickerTableViewCell = cell as! PickerCell

            if(pickerTableViewCell.pickerView == numClassesPicker.pickerView && numberOfRowsAtSection[2] < 5) {

                let newRowIndex = alertOptions.count - 4
                let newNumRows = 5

                if(!pickerTableViewCell.isExpanded() && pickerTableViewCell.rightLabelText() == numClasses[2]) {

                    alertOptions.insert("Number of Weeks", atIndex: 1)
                    numberOfRowsAtSection[2] = newNumRows

                    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: newRowIndex, inSection: 2)],
                        withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
                    tableView.reloadData()
                }

            } else if(numberOfRowsAtSection[2] == 5) {

                let oldRowIndex = alertOptions.count - 5
                let numRows = 4

                alertOptions.removeAtIndex(1)
                numberOfRowsAtSection[2] = numRows

                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: oldRowIndex, inSection: 2)],
                    withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
                tableView.reloadData()

            }
        }

        tableView.endUpdates()
```

And then in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` tableView delegate I have a condition to test how many rows are in `numberOfRowsAtSection[2]` and then return the type of cell I want accordingly

Comment: You could combine the lines ```if(cell.isKindOfClass(PickerCell))``` and ```let pickerTableViewCell = cell as! PickerCell``` for a more swifty approach of ```if let cell = cell as? PickerCell {}```